# Add a Grand Total footer to GridView table VS 2010

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, datagridview

I am trying to create a Grand Total of all values in a GridView table which will be displayed in the footer, I have started by creating the placeholder but not sure how to go about creating the grand total

```
        <FooterTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="lblGrandTotal" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
        </FooterTemplate>                  
    </asp:TemplateField>               
</Columns>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi in your gridview do this

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Amount">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lblAmount" runat="server" 
                   Text='<%# Eval("Amount","0:N2}").ToString %>'>
        </asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lblTotal" runat="server"></asp:Label>
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Now declare like public

```
Private grdTotal As Decimal = 0
```

After in the event RowDataBound from your gridview

```
If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
    Dim rowTotal As Decimal =
    Convert.ToDecimal(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "Amount"))
    grdTotal = grdTotal + rowTotal
End If
If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.Footer Then
    Dim lbl As Label = DirectCast(e.Row.FindControl("lblTotal"), Label)
    lbl.Text = grdTotal.ToString("N2")
End If
```

Comment: thanks for your answer! Could you explain the first bit about the gridview please

Comment: Sure well i created a TemplateField this haven't a datafield property so i put a label so i used the Text property to charge the data. As you know Eval is used to bind to an UI item that is setup to be read-only and is one way binding - for reading from a database into a UI field.

Comment: you wouldn't happen to know how I would subtract one column from another and put the result in the last column and then put a grand total on that?

Comment: hi check this link could be help you http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/es-ES/66f1d015-fecd-41de-bac5-959809c8b617/restar-columna-gridview but code is in C# so use this to change code http://www.elguille.info/NET/WebServices/deCSaVB_web.aspx

Answer (score 1):

If you are adding up just a single column, this should work..

**Code-Behind C#**

```
decimal totalA = 0;

protected void gvAlexandria_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    string totalAmtFinanced = ((Label)gvVehicleTEMP.FooterRow.FindControl("lblTotalAmtFinanced")).Text;

    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {        
        totalA += Convert.ToDecimal(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "AmtFinanced"));
    }
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Footer)
    {
        //Label lblTotal = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblTotal");

        if (totalAmtFinanced != null)
        {                   
            totalAmtFinanced = String.Format("{0:c}", totalA);
        }
    }
}
```

The column in my gridview that I am adding up is called AmtFinanced. This is how I total up a single column. If you have any problems, let me know!

Comment: thank you so much for your reply! You wouldn't happen to be able to post this in VB?

Comment: Dang, didn't even see that it was tagged VB. I would give it a shot but I do not recall the syntax for VB the slightest bit. Sorry about that!